# Using admin permission, how to authenticate or logged into the user account without a password?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

I'm new to with django application, I want to check/login a users account without password through admin permission.

Is there any built-in feature in Django? Please help or guide me on how to do that?

This kind of feature provided by laravel in PHP

Here is the sample code of PHP:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

public function loginAsUser(User $user){
    auth()->guard('admin')->logout();     
    auth()->guard('web')->loginUsingId($user->id);
    return redirect(route('user.dashboard'));
}
```

Comment: You can create a view which query the user based on email or username. Then call `login` method with that user object as a param.

Comment: You should check out the world class [dango docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/).  Docs don't get more new-user friendly than this.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Yes, but the authenticate method asking a user object with user.password and in my case - without password try to login user account using admin permission, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest logic that works for me.

```
[html / template page ]
<a href="{% url 'login_as' user.username %}">Login as User</a>

[urls.py]
path('login_as/<username>', views.login_as_user, name='login_as'),


[views.py]
from django.contrib.auth import login


@staff_member_required()
def login_as_user(request, username):
    try:
        # assuming the user name is passed in via get
        username = username
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)

        # manually set the backend attribute
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        login(request, user)
    except Exception as e:
        messages.warning(request, e)

    #location of landing 
    return redirect('/users/dashboard')
```